# Docusign - Azure AD SSO and invoking Rest API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, docusignapi

We are using Docusign with SSO configured to Azure AD using SAML.

My idea is to have a custom Single Page Application (SPA) which would be authenticated by Azure AD.

I have 2 separate Azure AD apps registered to Single Sign on to SPA and Docusign.

Is there a way I can make use of a **single access token** returned after logging in to the SPA to also invoke my Docusign API ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: A token is always only valid for one API/app. You can, however, get multiple tokens in your SPA. Have you checked the Azure AD app samples? You'd typically use MSAL.js in the front-end to get tokens.

Comment: you want to use Microsoft Azure token to make DocuSign API calls?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I have generated an access token for one but its not valid for the other. Basically I have added the Docusign App registration as "user_impersonation" under my SPA apps "API Permissions". Do you have more details on how to implement this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tokens for DocuSign are not useful for Azure and tokens for Azure are not useful for DocuSign.
There's no way to make API calls with Azure AD tokens to DocuSign.
We have a concept of SSO, but that is end-user feature which eventually result in you getting a token to DocuSign.
You would have to use OAuth for DocuSign to obtain token to make API calls into DocuSign directly.

Comment: Thank you Inbar... I was trying the other way also : Using the Docusign SSO App registration from within our Azure AD to have access to our backend App registration via API Permissions. My idea was once the person has done SSO to docusign, the same token received from our AD registration will be valid to invoke our backend service. I suppose this wont work either ? Its also better to have 2 separate app registrations for both of this ?